# AttributeError: 'Start' object has no attribute 'draw'

Tags: python, pygame, attributeerror

I am trying to learn python by making little programs. I am trying to make a small Chinese game program(via pygame), modelling some people from YouTube. 
I am trying to set up a start game sprite that when you collide with it and press a button it will switch to a new picture.

I have managed to get my Tiles to show up but I cant get my start game picture to get drawn. Because I want the player to collide with the start sprite I tried to put the Start image in another group, but when I try to get the program to display that group I get:

> AttributeError: 'Start' object has no attribute 'draw'

I have a few folders but only two relevant the main game called Class Test
and the sprite: called Hanzi

Here is my code: The new section is where I got the Start game group

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
import os
from Settings import *
from Sprites import *
from Hanzi import*
from Pinyin import*

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        pg.key.set_repeat(500, 100)
        self.load_data()

    def load_data(self):
        pass
#
    def new(self):
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(self, 1, 1)
        self.gameround =0
        self.startgame = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.startgame = Start(self, "StartGame")


        self.hanziwo1 = Tile(self,"Hao", 1)
        self.hanziwo2 = Tile(self,"Wo", 2)
        self.hanzishi3 = Tile(self, "Shi", 3)
        self.hanziren4 = Tile(self, "Ren", 4)
    def run(self):
        # game loop - set self.playing = False to end the game

        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def quit(self):
        pg.quit()
        sys.exit()

    def update(self):
        self.all_sprites.update()
        self.startgame.update()
    def draw_grid(self):
        for x in range(0, WIDTH, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.screen, LIGHTGREY, (x, 0), (x, HEIGHT))
        for y in range(0, HEIGHT, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.screen, LIGHTGREY, (0, y), (WIDTH, y))

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(BGCOLOR)
        self.draw_grid()
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        pg.display.flip()
        self.startgame.draw(self.screen)

    def events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.quit()
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    self.game.new.startgame.kill()
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.quit()
                if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                    self.player.move(dx=-1)
                if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                    self.player.move(dx=1)
                if event.key == pg.K_UP:
                    self.player.move(dy=-1)
                if event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                    self.player.move(dy=1)

    def show_start_screen(self):
        pass

    def show_go_screen(self):
        pass

# create the game object
g = Game()
g.show_start_screen()
while True:

    g.new()
    g.run()
    g.show_go_screen()
```

And then here are my sprite folder: The Tile class works but the Start class does not. I think it has something to do with the sprite group...

```
#Hanzi
import pygame as pg
import sys
from Settings import *
import Sprites
import os

game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)

Char_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, "Chin_Char1")

class Start(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, character):
        self.groups = game.startgame
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.character = character
        self.image = pg.image.load(os.path.join(Char_folder, self.character+".png")).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.image = pg.transform.scale(self.image,(TILESIZE*4,TILESIZE*4))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    # Apparently I dont even need an update section....? that is strange but not really because maybe if I need to change rounds it will need to be in the update section
    def update(self):
        x = 3
        y = 3

        self.rect.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.rect.y = y *TILESIZE

class Tile(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, character, location):
        self.game = game
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.character = character
        self.location = location
        self.image = pg.image.load(os.path.join(Char_folder, self.character+".png")).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.image = pg.transform.scale(self.image,(TILESIZE,TILESIZE))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    # Apparently I dont even need an update section....? that is strange but not really because maybe if I need to change rounds it will need to be in the update section
    #def update(self):
        x = -1
        y = 5
        if self.location <= 10:
            x += self.location
        if self.location >= 11:
            x += self.location -10
            y += self.location -10
        self.rect.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.rect.y = y *TILESIZE
```

Comment: your class `Start` doesn't have method `draw` - and this is why you get error. So what do you try to do with `Start.draw()` which you don't have ?

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: BTW: you don't add `Start` to group `self.startgame` but you replace it - `self.startgame = Start(self, "StartGame")` and maybe this is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To add element to group you have to use `add()`

```
    self.startgame.add( Start(self, "StartGame") )
```

but you replace group with `Start`

```
    self.startgame = Start(self, "StartGame")
```

and it makes problem